# How to quickly find k nearest points to a plane in 3 or more dimensions

Tags: geometry, point, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance, kdtree

I need to quickly find the k nearest points to a plane (or hyperplane) in 3 (or more) dimensions. Is there a fast way to perform this search, using some sort of clever data structure (similar to how a kd-tree works for k nearest neighbors)?

I know I can rotate the plane and all the points so that the plane is orthogonal to one of the axes, then measure the distance of each point to the plane by simply using the ordinate in that axis. However, the time complexity of this brute force approach is O(N), where (N) is the number of points. Since I have to find the k nearest neighbors for a large number of planes and a large number of points, I need to find a faster algorithm if possible.

Comment: The "or more" part of this is rather important. Up to how many dimensions are you looking at and how many points do you have? KD-trees are a common tool for this, but they aren't overly useful unless `N / log(N) < 2^D`,where `N` is the number of points and `D` is the number of dimenisons, as otherwise the KD-tree isn't much of an actual tree.

Comment: Three dimensions is the main target, but I'm considering adding surface normals and/or the reflectance of points into the distance function, so possibly 4, 6, or 7 dimensions. Even an implementation for 3 dimensions would be great though. I am using k-d trees already elsewhere, and yes, performance degrades to nearly linear even with 6 dimensions (or when the distance from the query point to the nearest neighbor is much greater than the distance between points in the k-d tree, even with 3 dimensions). I couldn't figure out how to adapt k-d trees for searching using a plane rather than a point.

Comment: You have quite a few options: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index
I would also review the wikipedia in full if you haven't already: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use any spatial data structure (kd-tree, R-tree, ...) that supports custom distance functions. You should be able to define a distance function that simply uses the distance to the plane instead of distance to a center point.

How to calculate this distance is described by @Spektre.

I have no idea how that scales, because it may depend on the kNN search algorithm used by the implementation.
However, I believe the standard algorithm (Hjaltason and Samet: "Distance browsing in spatial databases.") should at least be better than O(n).

In case you are using Java, the R-Tree, Quadtree and PH-Tree indexes in my [TinSpin](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) library all use this algorithm.

Comment: I looked a little bit into this and especially the custom search functions in sklearn. I don't see many problems. Usually the function requires objects of the same type. Here we would want point and plane. And also kd-trees require the same types for building and querying. We would build it with points only and query with a plane. I don't know of any implementation that supports that. I tried to look at TinSpin, but couldn't find documentation.

Comment: @Chris You are absolutely right, my bad. The way I implemented it, it always requires two points. However, it shouldn't be hard to adapt the algorithm to use distances to a plane (especially if axis-aligned). I can help you with that if you want. Since you are using python, it may make sense to interface with the c++ version (PH-Tree only) instead of Java. Let me know.

Answer (score -1):

measure the distance by using dot product with hyper plane normal... So let:

`n` - be the hyperplane normal unit vector

`p0` - be any point point on the hyperplane

`p[i]` - be i-th point from your pointcloud `i={ 0,1,2...n-1 }`

then the distance to hyperplane plane is:

```
d = |dot( p[i] - p0 , n )|
```

as you can see no need to transform/align anything and its `O(1)` without any expensive operations. I expect that any pre sorting of points or using clever structures will be slower than this in most cases...

Now you got 2 options either compute the `d` for each point and then quick sort which leads to `O(n.log(n))` time and `O(n)` space complexity.

Or remember `k` closest points on the run leading to `O(k*n)` time and `O(k)` space.

So if `k` is small `(k < log(n))` or you have not enough memory to spare use second approach otherwise use first one ...

Comment: This is no better than rotating all points. Both is O(n) or worse. We are looking for something better than that.

Comment: @Chris I doubt you can do better than `O(n)` without any additional information ...